# Display my returned JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

On my HTML Page, I have the following script.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/testservice.svc/rest/BillingPatterns', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){alert('test');},    
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

This returns **"Request failed: error"**

Using fiddler2 (inspects http traffic), I can see the request, and that the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 03 Nov 2011 16:11:05 GMT
Content-Length: 159

{"Anniversary":false,"BillingPatternCode":6,"BillingPatternDesc":"Monthly Anniversary ","Frequency":1,"Monthly":true,"QuarterDayType":null,"QuarterDays":false}
```

[image]

But it will not display. No matter what I have tried. Yes I have tried alert(data.BillingPatternDesc)

**EDIT:**
It doesnt seem to be executing the "success" function.

Comment: You have an absolute URL there. Are you trying to do a cross origin request (which won't work)? (Remove `http://localhost:1337` so the URI starts with `/` to make sure you are being relative).

Comment: There is a response from the webservice. Ill give it a quick try anyway. :)

Comment: Getting a response and being able to read it in JS are two different things.

Comment: when i return a object i set its name `someName`={"Anniversary":false}, is this not the case with JQuery $.ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as provided looks correct to me.  My guess is that the problem could be in your URL.  Your JSON request is to `http://localhost:1337/Myservice.svc/rest/BillingPatterns`; is the page running your script also running under `localhost:1337`?  If not, your browser will not allow you to fetch the JSON because it's considered a cross-domain request.

If you really need to get a JSON resource in a different domain/port, you could use JSONP instead.

Comment: The html page is just in my documents folder, on the same pc (local host). Thanks for pointing this out though.

Comment: It won't work, then; If you're running an HTML document from a file (`file://...`) and try to access `http://localhost:1337`, that is considered a cross-domain (even cross "zone") request.  You may have to convert to JSONP.

Comment: Well, ive not succesfully got the JSONP working, but It is definately a cross domain problem. (I moved my html to my localhost, and it works there)

Answer (score 2):

Try alert(data.d) instead of alert(data).

edit: don't think it's related, but you're missing a semi-colon after your alert.

edit2: if its not executing the success function, change your getJSON to $.ajax and provide an error callback to see what the problem is.

Comment: using the ajax now. With and without semi-colon it doesnt work. Theres an error callback? Ive been using firefox development tool, there are no js errors. ill give it a try though. :)

Comment: please see my updated code, It says error, (as im getting the textstatus), but how do i see the actual error?

Comment: yes, unfortunately the generic $.ajax is the only jquery ajax call that accepts an error callback. good source at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Comment: check all 3 parameters that jquery passes to your error callback - error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) for information about the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `alert(data.toSource());` or `console.log(data);`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toSource_date.asp

Comment: even that doesnt work :( . Thats actually something similar I did in ruby using REST, and was able to work backwards from the viewed structure to get what I want. Baffled at why its not working either. As for log, unless it saves elsewhere, it is not diplaying on the page.

Comment: What happens if you just do a simple `alert('just testing');` inside the `getJSON` callback function? Maybe the function is not even running...

Comment: Okay, nothing :/ Any reasons as to why the function isnt running? I can call up the example code just fine, and I know the call part is working.